# Android Marshmallow requestPermissions WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

After three days of searching I realized that the android 6 or change permissions.
But I fail to ask oermisiunea to save a file.
I probably groza examples but it did not, I did something wrong.
Please help.

```
    String url = "http://grupovrt.ddns.net:81/v4.2.apk";
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setDescription("Virtual Romania Tv UPDATE");
        request.setTitle("UPDATE Virtual Romania Tv");
// in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        }
        if (!checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                R.string.title_activity_categori))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not allowed to save files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            // try to save the file

            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/update", "v4.2.apk");

        }


// get download service and enqueue file
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
```

Error: Error:(108, 49) error: cannot find symbol variable WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Edit.

I did seek if given permission to write.
but I do not know how to ask permission if it is not.
Please help me, I tried everything I found on google but could not. I'm a beginner.

```
 if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Descarc noi actualizari!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            String url = "http://grupovrt.ddns.net:81/v4.2.apk";
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setDescription("Virtual Romania Tv UPDATE");
            request.setTitle("UPDATE Virtual Romania Tv");

            // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                // get download service and enqueue file
                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                manager.enqueue(request);


                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Descarc noi actualizari!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/update", "v4.2.apk");
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Nu ai permisiunea sa descarci!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Trebuie sa oferi acces la spatiul de stocare!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 110);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 110);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Descarc noi actualizari!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your code I recommend you to use next code:

1. Create a OnPermissionRequested interface:

   ```
   public interface OnPermissionRequested {
       void onGranted();
   }
   ```
2. In activities/fragments add next methods to check permission. You also can create a main activity and fragment and extend to avoid duplicated code:

   ```
   OnPermissionRequested mPermissionRequest;

   protected void requestPermission(String permission, OnPermissionRequested listener) {

       mPermissionRequest = listener;

       // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission)
               != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied, try again later please.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           } else {
               // request the permission.
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                       new String[]{permission}, 2456);
           }
       } else {
           mPermissionRequest.onGranted();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                      String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
       if (grantResults.length > 0
           && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           if (mPermissionRequest != null)
               mPermissionRequest.onGranted();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Call requestPermission method where you need check the permission and set the second argument with the action you want to do if the permission is granted.

   ```
   requestPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
       new OnPermissionRequested() {
           @Override
           public void onGranted() {
               // what you want to do
               createPdf();
           }
       });
   ```

I hope you find it useful. Good luck